# What is the replacement for @BeforeMethod annotation in Robot Framework - Selenium Library?

Tags: selenium, automation, robotframework

I need to execute some keyword before each and every test cases.
Assume I have a .robot file which has 4 test cases, and I need to run a keyword, 4 times before executing those 4 test cases. In TestNG, we can use @BeforeMethod annotation. I would like to know what can be used to do that from Robot Framework?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following are the keywords in robot framework as the replacements for execution hooks.

```
┌────────────────┬───────────────────────┐
│ Robot Keyword  │ TestNG Execution Hook │
├────────────────┼───────────────────────┤
│ Test Setup     │ @BeforeMethod         │
│ Test Teardown  │ @AfterMethod          │
│ Suite Setup    │ @BeforeSuite          │
│ Suite Teardown │ @AfterSuite           │
└────────────────┴───────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 6):

`Test Setup`, `Test Teardown`, Test Timeout keywords can be used to specify function that needs to be called before each test case. 
 - `Test Setup` will act as `@Before/@BeforeMethod` in Junit/Testng respectively
 - `Test Teardown` will act as `@After/@AfterMethod` in JUnit/Testng 
 - `[Setup]   Keyword` - will be used if you want to execute `@BeforeTest` for only that test case. 
Please refer below example-

```
*** Settings ***
Library         OperatingSystem
Suite Setup     This Is Suite Startup Keyword
Suite Teardown  This Is Suite TearDown Keyword
Test Setup      This Is Before Test
Test Teardown   This Is After Test

*** Keywords ***
This Is Suite Startup Keyword
    Log To Console      This Is Suite Startup Keyword

This Is Suite TearDown Keyword

    Log To Console      This Is Suite TearDown Keyword

This Is Before Test
    Log To Console      This Is Before Test

This Is After Test
    Log To Console      This Is After Test

This Is Special Execution Case
    Log To Console      This Is Special Execution Case


*** Test Cases ***
Test Case One
    [setup]             This Is Special Execution Case
    Log To Console      This Is My Test Case 1

Test Case Two
    Log To Console      This Is My Test Case 2

Test Case Three
    Log To Console      This Is My Test Case 3
```

For more details refer [Robot Framework User Guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#suite-setup-and-teardown) section Initialization files and 2.4.5   Suite setup and teardown.

Comment: Please extend your sample with the suite level [`Test Setup` and case level `[Setup]`](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-setup-and-teardown) settings - they are the analogies of TestNG's `@beforeTest` annotation. The `Suite Setup` is actually the `@beforeSuite` annotation.

Comment: Nice suggestion, Updated example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Robotframework `Test Setup` setting, to define a keyword that will be ran before each case in the suite.
If you want to specify a setup on specific case, that's fine with the `[Setup]` - and if set, it will override the setup set in suite level:

```
*** Settings ***
Test Setup      Log    this is ran for every case

*** Test Cases ***
Case 1
    Do Something

Case 2
    [Setup]    Log    Custom case setup
    Do Something Else

Case 3
    Do The Third Thing
```

When Case 1 and Case 3 are ran, you'll see before their execution the message "this is ran for every case", but not for Case 2 - it has an overriden setup, and you'll see its message ("Custom case setup")